# Backbone.js - How to make sub models within Main models?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

In my app, i have main naivgation link with sublinks (drop down menus) - i am calling my collection from navigation view, and i am getting the json response like this:

```
[{"label": "General","link":"#/general",
  "subLinks": [{"label": "Dashboard",     "link": "#/dashboard"},
               {"label": "My Task",       "link": "#/mytask"},
               {"label": "My Documents",  "link": "#/mydocuments"},
               {"label": "My Templates",  "link": "#/mytemplates"},
               {"label": "Repositories",  "link": "#/reposotories",  "subLinks": []},
               {"label": "SavedSearches", "link": "#/savedSearches", "subLinks": []}
]
```

my question is how to convert this in to backbone models.. especially how can i handle the sublinks relation of each main links..? (how to make nested models in main model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse).

With `parse`, you are in control of translating the raw response to your model object. There, for instance, you could take the raw `subLinks` array and feed it to a `Collection` of yours, and then set the popoluated collection as a property of your `Model`.

Comment: Let me try your suggestion. thanks - additional question, in case if my json contains more details than navigation links - what would be the way..?

Comment: What do you mean? You can recursively apply that and map arrays to `Collections`, simple properties to simple properties and complex properties to `Models`